# rake assets:precompile showing up locally instead of in S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, asset-pipeline

`rake assets:precompile` currently spits everything into my `public/assets` directory when I was under the impression (after setting up S3) that it would push up to Amazon.  I am utilizing `asset_sync` as outlined [here](http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/s3-asset-hosting-walkthrough)

Currently I have this in my `application.rb`:

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  config.assets.enabled = true
  config.assets.digest = true
end
```

Then in my `development.rb` I have:

```
  config.action_controller.asset_host =  "//#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY_DEV']}.s3.amazonaws.com"
  config.action_mailer.asset_host = "http://#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY_DEV']}.s3.amazonaws.com"
  config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Unless you're using something like asset_sync the copying to s3 thing won't happen automatically

Comment: sorry @FrederickCheung I am using `asset_sync`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must appreciate that `asset_sync` is there to *sync* your assets (not replace them)

---

**Asset Sync**

The gem itself will let Rails publish your assets "locally" (to `/public/assets`), and then it will essentially push them all to your S3 bucket, *replicating* them.

As described by the [gem's documentation](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync):

> Synchronises Assets between Rails and S3.
>
> Asset Sync is built to run with the new Rails Asset Pipeline feature
>   introduced in Rails 3.1. After you run bundle exec rake
>   assets:precompile your assets will be synchronised to your S3 bucket,
>   optionally deleting unused files and only uploading the files it needs
>   to.

--

**Fix**

In regards to your problem, I'm sure that by default, development assets are served *dynamically* - meaning that if you want to run them as *static* (precompiled), you'll have to [tweak some of the settings](http://dennisreimann.de/blog/precompiling-rails-assets-for-development/) which define this:

```
  #config/environments/development.rb
    # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
    # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
    # number of complex assets.
    config.assets.debug = false #true
```

This *should* enable you to use the precompiled assets locally (in development), which will in turn allow you to use S3

Production serves static assets by default, meaning the most applicable way to test `asset_sync` is literally by deploying to your production environment. However, you should be able to use the code above to get it to work in development, too

Comment: Thanks Rich.  This works - my assets in development are now being served via S3.  Thank you so much!